# find method does not return resultset in Naming Field Convention Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following cakephp query:

```
$this->request->data = $this->AnsMatrixLubrication->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('eq_model' => $eq_model)
));
```

The output is something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [AnsMatrixLubrication] => Array ( 
            [id] => 228 
            [matrix_lubrication_id] => 1 
            [eq_model] => D11 R 
            [A] => x 
            [B] => x 
            [C] => x 
            [D] => x 
            [E] => x 
            [F] => x 
            [G] => x 
            [H] => x 
            [created] => 2014-08-15 20:40:06 
            [modified] => 2014-08-15 20:40:06 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [AnsMatrixLubrication] => Array ( 
            [id] => 229 
            [matrix_lubrication_id] => 2 
            [eq_model] => D11 R 
            [A] => y 
            [B] => y 
            [C] => y 
            [D] => y 
            [E] => y 
            [F] => y 
            [G] => y 
            [H] => y 
            [created] => 2014-08-15 20:40:06 
            [modified] => 2014-08-15 20:40:06 
        ) 
    )
)
```

But I need the output in [Cake naming convention](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions), I mean `[Model][0][field_name]`.
Why doesn't the `find` method show the output in CakePHP naming convention? If it should be the default behavior and How can I solve that?

**Edit**
CakePHP version: 2.4.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The conventions depend on what you are trying to do, saving associated/single/many records, creating form elements, etc... The structure returned by `Model::find()` is in the expected and correct format. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ndm. I understand the point but is there a way to achieve that I want to do? Because I need to show many records in an edit form (via `$this->request->data`) and the format output of `find('all)` doesn't match with the format of form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link solve my problem.

http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/10/27/editing-multiple-records-with-saveall/

With the function `Set::combine()` I can convert the `find('all')` output to form field convention.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### That *is* the expected format

As shown [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-all) that's the expected return format for a find all call:

> The results of a call to find('all') will be of the following form:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [ModelName] => Array
            (
                [id] => 83
                [field1] => value1
                [field2] => value2
                [field3] => value3
            )

        [AssociatedModelName] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [field1] => value1
                [field2] => value2
                [field3] => value3
            )

    )
)
```

### Form fields and find calls aren't the same thing

The [docs you've linked to](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions) are for the naming conventions of form fields (emphasis added):

> If you need to **specify multiple fields** using the same field name, thus creating an array that can be saved in one shot with saveAll(), use the following convention:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.0.fieldname');
echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.1.fieldname');
```

This makes no reference to the structure of data returned by find-all (though if for example a find on Post hasMany Comment were made - the comments data would be in the format you're currently expecting).